# Null Parameters in AJAX POST to Spring Controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, post

I'm having trouble doing an ajax POST to a Spring Controller using jquery.
The post contains several parameters, among which is a base 64 string that represents a file sent from the client side.
Now, if the file is under 1,5~2mb, the request gets done just fine.
If it surpasses this size, the controller returns that the request is syntatically incorrect.
I'm using encodeuricomponent in the client side.

In both scenarios, if I get the reader from the HTTPServletRequest, I can get the entire POST form. Needless tosay, it's super slow.
If the file is above 2 mb, I can also get the entire query by the method referenced above, but not by the getParameter() method(HTTPServletRequest) nor by annotations (@requestParam("file")).

This is my controller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadClient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadClient( Model model, HttpServletRequest req,@RequestParam(value="file", required = false) String file, @RequestParam(value="projectID") Integer projectID, 
            @RequestParam(value="opID") Integer opID, @RequestParam(value="releaseID") Integer releaseID,
            @RequestParam(value="name") String name, @RequestParam(value="url") String url, 
            @RequestParam(value="date") String date,
            @RequestParam(value="version") String version, @RequestParam(value="comment") String comment,
            @RequestParam(value="fileName") String fileName){
```

Answer (score 0):

For uploading files using Spring, try using the multipart support. Refer to the link [Spring's multipart (fileupload) support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html)